# Find files across all drives using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I know how to search for files using dir/gci, but that only works across one drive AFAIK.

- Is there a way to search across all drives on the computer?
- Is there a way without manually enumerating then looping through the drives?
- Is there a way to access the search indexes/services that are already available in windows, to speed up the search?

Answer (score 3):

This will list all ZIP files in decending size order by directory on all available drives:

```
get-psdrive -p "FileSystem" `
| % {write-host -f Green "Searching " $_.Root;get-childitem $_.Root -include *.ZIP -r `
| sort-object Length -descending}
```

Or search a specified list of Drives/Shares (e.g. C:, D: and \SERVER1\SHARE1...)

```
$paths="C:\","D:\","\\SERVER1\SHARE1" `
| % {write-host -f Green "Searching " $_;get-childitem $_ -include *.ZIP -r `
| sort-object Length -descending}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$drive = get-psdrive
foreach ($a in $drive) {gci}
```

Not so bad... I can't think of a way without recursing all the drives like this, though.

See [this page](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/wdscmdlet.aspx) for info on searching the index.